# Download file to phone with and without sdcard

Tags: android

I am novice programming android. I want to write a simple application that gets updated. For this I use a simple function that can download a file and show the current progress in a ProgressDialog and I store the file in the phone´s Sdcard like this:

```
output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");
```

It would be some problem with the phones that not have SdCard? How can I solve it to work in any phone? Thank you.

Comment: When there is no SDCard, you can store files in Internal Storage. For same check - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html This is a documentation link, which will help you in solving your problem. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an internal storage in Android devices, so you can utilize that.
I think, the default path to a private storage is "/data/data/package_name/files/file_name.extension".
Try this code:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("file name here", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String str = "data";
fOut.write(str.getBytes());
fOut.close();
```

For further information, look this resources:

Section "[Save a File on Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage)" of the official Android documentation;
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_internal_storage.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's not only dealing with the problem phones without SDCard MMC, you'll find phones running without AOSP distribution. In fact, I saw some non-official Android mods (a lot of Chinese phones sold over the world) and you get no guarantee to find /sdcard filesystem in all of them.
If you got root permissions (rooted phone) you can program your app to read fstab and find out which storage filesystem is mounted at.
So, without knowing what Android distribution will run your app, I can tell you I found /data directory at all distros I saw.

Hope it helps.

Regards